# LINQ: Getting item from dictionary by key and also its values then assign them to variable

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In Parts class we have Data dictionary that contains key "Number" and value "1" for example. The key is always called "Number" and the value is always string of some number 1,2,3 etc. I want to assign to one variable (List) all items that has the key "number" with their values and then to group them by the id in Parts. So in the end the result should be the Id from Parts, Number and its value.

```
   public class People
   {
   public List<Parts> Parts { get; set; }
   }


   public class Parts
   {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public Dictionary<string,string> Data {get;set}
   }

   var msf = new People();
```

Currently my example that does not work properly with linq :

```
 var temp = msf
   .Parts
   .Select(s => s.Data.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains("Number"))
   .ToList()
   .Select(s = > s.Value));
```

Can someone give me better solution for this scenario code with linq?

```
  "People":[  
  "id":"1234567"

   "Parts":[

   "id":"234567",
   "name":"Lqlq"
   "Data":{ 
   "number" : "1"
     }

  "id":"3424242",
   "name":"Lqlq2"
   "Data":{ 
   "number" : "2"
     }
 ]
    ]
```

Comment: You can't have more than one entry with the same key so your question doesn't make sense to me. Could you try again, maybe provide a sample of entries from your Dictionary?

Comment: Could you provide 3 or 4 example data of input and how the output should be for them?

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work properly. For example what do you expect to get from that code and what do you get

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> dict = msf.Part .Where(x => !string.Empty(x.Id ))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Id, y => y.Name)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Dictionary `Data` can't contain several keys with name "Number" and different values. I think question should be updated with samples.

Comment: I edited it with example how this looks in json file.

Comment: You wrote: " I want to assign to one variable all items that has the key "number" with their values". You didn't use the word item before. Do you mean that you want several properties of "all Part that have a key equal to number in its dictionary"?

Comment: Yep. The idea is to have list of all ids that match the value of the number, so if we have different ids but equal number to have them in the list. So the result should be list of ids ,number property and value of the number where number is equal to other , so if we have 3 different ids but in Data we have Number equal to 1 for the three of them to have them in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` containing a list of ID strings for each "Number" value:

```
var idsByNumber = msf.Parts.Where(p => p.Data.ContainsKey("number"))    // filter for all that have a number
             .Select(p => new { ID = p.ID, Number = p.Data["number"] }) // select ID and the number value
             .GroupBy(x => x.Number)                                    // group by number
             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList()); // create dictionary number -> id list
```

Comment: This will group them by number ,but how to take only the numbers that have equal values. Because I need only the ids that have number with equal numbers.

Comment: @Sarah I don't understand, it _is_ grouping them by the _value_ of the "number"-entry in the `Data`-Dictionary. `pData["number"]` returns the value.

Comment: "People":[  
  "id":"1234567"

   "Parts":[

   "id":"234567",
   "name":"Lqlq"
   "Data":{ 
   "number" : "1"
     }

  "id":"3424242",
   "name":"Lqlq2"
   "Data":{ 
   "number" : "1"
     }
 ]
    ]

if we have equal numbers like in this case only then to add them in this list.

Comment: What my code does _is grouping them by those numbers_ ("grouping" means that it puts together those elements with _equal_ numbers). So in your case the resulting dictionary `idsByNumber` would contain exactly one key `1` (because you only use the number 1), and for that key, the dictionary would contain a list containing the ids `23456` and `3424242`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative syntax.

```
var temp = from part in msf.Parts
        where part.Data["Number"] == "2"
        select part;
```

Usually is a good idea to ask your questions using an MCVE - here's some code that can be pasted in Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var msf = new People() {
        Parts = new List<Parts> {
            new Parts { Name = "Lqlq", Id = "234567", Data = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Number", "1"} } },
            new Parts { Name = "Lqlq2", Id = "3424242", Data = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Number", "2"} } },
        }
    };
    var temp = from part in msf.Parts
        where part.Data["Number"] == "2"
        select part
    ;

    temp.Dump();
}

public class People
{
    public List<Parts> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Parts
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```